# Different set of files generated by angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm a beginner in angular2, I'm following different bits of tutorials. Below is the structure of their files:

Link of tutorial relative to image below:

https://www.udemy.com/ultimate-angular-2/learn/v4/t/lecture/5723842

[image]

Link of tutorial relative to image below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBjPIabiRNg

[image]

Mine is different it's missing the config, dist, node_modules, tmp and typings folder:

[image]

I'm using these versions:

```
$node -v
v6.6.0
$npm -v
3.10.7
$ng -v
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 6.6.0
os: darwin x64
```

**Error of the angular-cli installation:**

https://gist.github.com/kim-montano/df9d492ce83768b744fc9a5f6d8bf498

**Steps I did:**

1. Downloaded: https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
2. I ran this command: $ npm install -g angular-cli
3. Went to a folder in the documents where I want the angular2 project
   to appear.
4. Typed this: ng new first-app

Comment: have u got any errors when you install it using cli command..?

Comment: Hi @Outlooker, I've edited my question. I included a link so you can look at the error logs. IDK if this is important but I didn't use sudo since I followed the instruction here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I also included the steps I did prior to generating the new project.

Comment: could you please post your package.json file..?

Comment: Outlooker thanks for looking into this. Here's the package generated by angular-cli: https://gist.github.com/kim-montano/b827d6bc62eb04439e4a6f6383ffb9c6

Comment: Could you check if the node-gyp meets the requirements https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#user-content-installation

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that as 1.0.0-beta.15 was released yesterday (20/09/2016), the tutorial you are viewing is using an older version of the CLI, which *could* have a different file structure.

It would be useful if you provided more details, in order for people to be able to assist you.

---

**Update:** You mention that you are missing `node_modules` folder. This may be because you have not run `npm install` to install the project dependencies. The `tmp` and `dist` folders are relevant to when you do a build of your project.

Comment: What details would you need? I can provide them if you'd like. So far I've provided the versions of the packages I've used.

Comment: What/who is `their files` that you mention on the first line of your post. Link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: I've edited my question please take a look, I also added the errors I have encountered while installing angular-cli.